# Mean Std in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, mean, standard-deviation

Having a pandas data frame as follow:

```
   a   b
0  1  12
1  1  13
2  1  23
3  2  22
4  2  23
5  2  24
6  3  30
7  3  35
8  3  55
```

I want to find the mean standard deviation of column b in each group.
My following code give me 0 for each group.

```
stdMeann = lambda x: np.std(np.mean(x))
print(pd.Series(data.groupby('a').b.apply(stdMeann)))
```

Comment: why not just: `df.groupby('a')['b'].mean()`?

Comment: with `np.std(np.mean(x))` you are taking the std dev of the mean.  the mean is a constant.  the standard dev of any scalar is zero.

Comment: I think this is what you meant:  `df.groupby('a')['b'].mean().std()` or maybe you want `df.groupby('a')['b'].std().mean()`?  The key is that you are doing a groupby operation and then a second operation on those results

Comment: `data.groupby('a').b.agg(['mean','std'])`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As noted in the comments you can use [`.agg` to aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once) by multiple statistics:

```
In [11]: df.groupby("a")["b"].agg([np.mean, np.std])
Out[11]:
   mean        std
a
1    16   6.082763
2    23   1.000000
3    40  13.228757
```

pandas let's you pass dispatch strings, rather than using the numpy function:

```
In [12]: df.groupby("a")["b"].agg(["mean", "std"])  # just b
Out[12]:
   mean        std
a
1    16   6.082763
2    23   1.000000
3    40  13.228757

In [13]: df.groupby("a").agg(["mean", "std"])  # all columns
Out[13]:
     b
  mean        std
a
1   16   6.082763
2   23   1.000000
3   40  13.228757
```

You can also specify what to do on a per-column basis:

```
In [14]: df.groupby("a").agg({"b": ["mean", "std"]})
Out[14]:
     b
  mean        std
a
1   16   6.082763
2   23   1.000000
3   40  13.228757
```

---

Note: the reason you were getting 0s was that [`np.std`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) of a single number is 0 (it's a little surprising to me that it's not an error, but there we are):

```
In [21]: np.std(1)
Out[21]: 0.0
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure that pandas is depreciating dictionary support for agg.